# A property of families of rectangles

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. By rectangle, we mean a Cartesian product of subsets of $X$. Let $S$ and $T$ be families of rectangles. Are there any equivalent conditions to:

> for any rectangle $R$ from $S$ there exists a finite collection of rectangles of $T$ such that $R$ is a subset of union of this collection and vice versa.

Comment: You probably mean a rectangle is the product of *two* subsets of $X$? Or just one subset with itself?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "By rectangle, we mean a Cartesian product of a subset of ". Is there a way to express this question a more symbolically?

Comment: A rectangle is "a Cartesian product of a subset of X" and what?  It may well be that I am just ignorant about how to express what you are saying, but a product of a and {} has no meaning for me.  It might help to explain this further.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake.